# How extract words between square brackets?

Tags: php, string

I have a string on the following format:

```
[ GroupOne : 2015 | 10/12 | A ] && [ GroupTow : 2015 | 10/20 | C ] && [ GroupThree : 2015 | 10/15 | B ]
```

To extract the first words within the first the square brackets by preg_match

```
//Only the first part
$Number_Group //GroupOne
$Yers = //2015
$Data = //10/12
$Type = //A
```

Comment: Is it consistent that a colon and only two pipes will always separate the data? Have you tried any regexs yet?

Comment: For strings like this, [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not with preg match but it works

```
<?php

    $cad = "[ GroupOne : 2015 | 10/12 | A ] && [ GroupTow : 2015 | 10/20 | C ] && [ GroupThree : 2015 | 10/15 | B ]";

    $values = explode('&&', $cad);

    $part1 = explode(':', substr(trim($values[0]), 1, -1));
    $Number_Group = $part1[0];
    echo $Number_Group . '<br/>';

    $other = explode('|', $part1[1]);
    $Year = $other[0];
    echo $Year . '<br/>';   

    $Data = $other[1];
    echo $Data . '<br/>';   

    $Type = $other[2];
    echo $Type . '<br/>';   

    ?>
```

Comment: How can be divided
$Number_Group = 'GroupOne';
$Yers = '2015';
$Data = '10/12';
$Type = 'A';

Comment: you only need this values?